# "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type" for a code that was running perfectly fine?

Tags: matlab, file, for-loop, directory

I have some MATLAB code that I worked on with someone who is much more experienced in MATLAB than I am. The code was running perfectly fine the other day. When I tried running it today, I got the error "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type" and I have tried reading through many other stack overflow questions on the topic, but still struggling to resolve my issue. I will include the code up until the error below. Based on what I've read, it might be something to do with structure? I would appreciate any help or tips you could send my way. Thank you!

```
for j = 3:length(files)

files(j).name
folder_name = files(j).folder;
file2load = strcat(folder_name, '\', files(j).name);

data_input = load(file2load);

trace_names = fieldnames(data_input);

for i = 1:length(trace_names)

    data_to_plot.x = data_input.(char(trace_names(i))).data.x;
    data_to_plot.y = data_input.(char(trace_names(i))).data.y;
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to know what data type `files` is, presumably not a struct or table which MATLAB is expecting if you're using dot indexing

Comment: Hello! it is 22x1 struct array... so must I change the data type of 'files'?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, it will indicate where exactly the error happens. You suggest that it's the `data_to_plot.y` line  at the bottom that causes the error, but there are 4 dot indexing operations there, MATLAB should indicate which of them is the culprit. You also don't show how  you initialize `data_to_plot`. What is it?

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me as I navigate this-- Full error message: Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in Probability_response_plots_attempt (line 37)
        data_to_plot.x = data_input.(char(trace_names(i))).data.x;   and in terms of initializing data_to_plot, the two lines with .x and .y are the first time I use it. should there be a separate line that initializes it?

Comment: thank u, i realized that I had some different file types in the directory i was pulling from. i appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, it is not clear *why* you are getting this error, but I can tell you *what* is causing it. 'Dot indexing' is a way of accessing data fields in a type of Matlab variable called a `struct`. In your snippet `files(j)` is not a `struct`.

For example, you cannot do this:

```
>> s = {}; % s is a cell array (not a struct)
>> g = {};
>> g{1} = 'lala';
>> s{1} = g;
>> s.g % cannot access g using this syntax
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
```

But if you make `s` a `struct`, you can:

```
>> s = struct
s = 
  struct with no fields.

>> s.item1 = g; % create a field called item1 to hold the stuff in g
>> s.item1 % now you can use dot indexing to access the stuff you put in there

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {'lala'}
```

I would guess that this snippet is part of a function where `files` is an argument or down the line of a script in which `files` is earlier defined. Probably the other day with your colleague, you had `files` set to a variable that is indeed an array of structures with the items `name` etc inside of them. Since then, something changed the value of `files` to an array of non-struct types.